# Antd File upload not getting reset

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form. where file upload is mandatory. Validation works fine first time no file uploaded, but when i upload and delete file, Form doesn't throw validation error.
Here is stakbiz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x27nfd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getValueFromEvent` prop on `Form.Item` component like this:

```
const normFile = (e) => {
  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }
  return e && e.fileList;
};
...
<Form.Item
    label="File"
    name="file"
    getValueFromEvent={normFile}
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Please input your File!',
      },
    ]}
  >
   ... 
</Form.Item>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x27nfd-vuefkt) is edited version of your stackblitz link.