# How to delete a file in antd Upload component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have this Upload component that I got from antd : [react ant design documentation](https://ant.design/components/upload/)

```
<Upload
  beforeUpload={()=> {
    return false; }}
  onChange={e => onChangeFile(e, index)}
  onRemove={e => onRemoveFile(e, index)}
>
  <Button
    icon={<UploadOutlined />}
  >
    Upload a file
  </Button>
</Upload>
```

After uploading the file, a remove icon appears. When I click on the remove button the file does not get removed from the state.

here is the onChange function :

```
const onChangeFile = (info, index) => {
    console.log("onChange info = " + info);
    const newForm = form;
    newForm.inputs[index].value = info.file;
    setForm({
      ...form,
      from: newForm
    });
    console.log("onChange form = " + form);
};
```

I tried removing it using onRemove function like this:

```
const onRemoveFile = (info, index) => {
   console.log("onRemove info = " + info);
   const newForm = form;
   newForm.inputs[index].value = null;
   setForm({
     ...form,
     from: newForm
   });
   console.log("onRemove form = " + form);
};
```

the output of the console logs :

[image]

screenshot of the UI:

[image]

feel free to try a few things in this code example provided by antd:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qj6n3?file=/index.js

Comment: use it with antd `<Form>`, it will automatically handle many scenarios

Comment: I am using it inside a <Form> then a <Form.Item>. But I can't figure out how to delete the uploaded file.

Comment: on submit of form antd form always returns the updated values

Comment: you don't need to write a function to remove a file

Comment: yeah but the updated state of the file input always contains the file even after deleting it.

Comment: don't create a state for it, get filelist value onsubmit of form

Comment: I have a form state that gets values from multiple other inputs, I need to change its state when I upload the file.

Comment: posted the answer, I hope you'll find it helpful, thanls

Comment: will try it and give you feedback. Thank you so much for allocating your time to help me solve this issue.

Comment: maybe your problem is the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419650/antd-file-upload-not-getting-reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by following this example:

```
const normFile = (e) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
};

<Form onFinish={() => {}}>
    <Form.Item
        name="tagList"
        label="Upload"
        valuePropName="list"
        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
        rules={[
            {
                required: true,
                message: 'Tag list is required',
            },
        ]}
    >
        <Upload
            beforeUpload={() => false}
            listType="picture-card"
        >
            <UploadOutlined style={{ marginRight: 5 }} />
            Upload
        </Upload>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```